# How to start using ndepend?

Tags: .net, static-analysis, ndepend

I recently downloaded ndepend and ran an analysis on an open source project I participate in.

I did not now where to look next - a bit of visual and information overload and it turned out I don't even know where to start.

Can anyone suggest starting points?

- What information should I look for first?
- What points out problems in the code (in a BIG way)?
- What would the low hanging fruit that can immediately seen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Scott Hanselman / Stuart Celarier / Patrick Cauldwell's [poster](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EducatingProgrammersWithPlacematsNDependStaticAnalysisPoster.aspx) with ndepend metrics has some useful information on it. Rather than trying to break down all the heuristics being used I'd focus on only a few at a time starting with "zone of pain / zone of uselessness" and cyclomatic complexity.

There is also a [podcast](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast51StaticCodeAnalysisWithNDepend.aspx) which covers some of the basics of the tool.

Between that and running nDepend on a few different projects you may be able to start gathering useful data that you can make into insights.

Answer (score 15):

When starting with NDepend, the most important thing is to understand what [Code Rule over LINQ (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) can bring to your shop by letting you define queries on your code and rules. [Here you'll find a summary and source code of all 200 default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html).

The second most important thing to look at is dependencies, with both the [dependency graph view](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx), that works hand-in-hand with the [dependency matrix view](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx). Once you master these 2 views, you'll be able to pinpoint where the code is well layered or not, and where developers made mistake.

Then it'll be time to learn more in-depth feature, such as the possibility to [compare 2 versions of your code base](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#BuildComparison), the [various code metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#Metrics) and why they are useful, enforcing statically  [purity and immutability](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#Immutable), controlling automatically [test coverage](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#Coverage)...

Comment: IME it's not actually possible to "master these 2 views" in the eval version.   The matrix will close itself after 7 clicks (I'm screaming at the monitor after the third time that happens), and the graph is likely to be an incredibly dense postage stamp that you can't zoom.   I wish there was a proper eval of this product - every Internet rave-review is written by someone with a free copy, and though I am not at all mean about spending money on tools, I have never, ever, been able to convince myself NDepend is useful.  Perhaps that's because the eval version isn't actually useful.

Comment: Just ask the NDepend's support and get your 2 weeks pro eval

Comment: Will, finally with version 4 we switched from a time-unlimited feature limited eval mode, to a 14-day time-limited fully functional eval mode.

Comment: Patrick - that's cool.  Of course, after your original response above, I did buy V3, and I upgraded to V4 on the day you released it... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Excellent pair of web casts (30 minute videos) where Patrick Smacchia and Filip Ekberg talk through some of the features of nDepend and how to use them:

http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2012/10/31/two-screencasts-on-how-to-demystify-spaghetti-code/